# Smooth animation for expansion/collapse of child nodes in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to expand/collapse child nodes on zoom in/zoom out (by checking for a threshold radius) and currently the expand/collapse step happens abruptly without any transition...

[image]

How can I get the child nodes to pop out of the parent node smoothly with a nice cubic ease-out transition?

Comment: Add a transition on the position of the nodes and links starting from the node they are expanded from.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm toggling the nodes using `d.children/d._children`. How do I apply transitions in that scenario? Applying transitions to nodes and links inside `tick()` transitions everything (including node movements during zoom, pan and initialization). How do I target just the child node pop out movement?

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention that you're using the force layout. In this case you'd need to dynamically adjust the positions (i.e. transition manually) in the tick handler -- not trivial to implement.